# View Shared Tasks in Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-2016

I have shared a Task List with another user in my business but I can't see how they can view these task through the 'To-Do Bar' in the main email page(the taskbar on the right-hand side).

They can see their own tasks fine, just not the ones I have shared with them and made them 'Owner'.

Anyone any idea if this is actually possible?  We are using Outlook 2016.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can only view someone else's tasks from the main tasks window